# ¿Cómo separar de una cadena la clave y valor separados por un delimitador en Java?

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando en separar los datos query de una URL, es decir la clave y valor dentro de una cadena, el conjunto está separado por el delimitador & y la clave con el valor el carácter =

Muestra a separar:

```
param1=one&param2=two&param3=three
```

Lo que tengo hecho más o menos funciona, pero el orden que me crea la lista es invertido, es decir que el primer parámetro del `HashMap` es param3 el segundo param2 y el tercero param1, yo quiero mantener el orden que aparece en la cadena a extraer.

```
private Map<String, String> listParams = new HashMap<>();

private void splitQuery()  {
        if (url.getQuery() != null) {
            final String[] pairs = url.getQuery().split("&");

            for (String pair : pairs) {
                final int idx = pair.indexOf("=");
                String key = null;
                String value = null;
                try {
                    key = idx > 0 ? URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), "UTF-8") : pair;
                    value = idx > 0 && pair.length() > idx + 1 ? URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), "UTF-8") : null;
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(key + ":" + value);
                listParams.put(key, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si buscas mantener el orden en que se ingresaron los datos, utiliza [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) en lugar de `HashMap`, y tu problema queda resuelto:

```
private Map<String, String> listParams = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```